# How to call method in the class?

Tags: python, python-class

I'm using classes to practice but I don't know how to use them properly.

Here I want to put the class in another file, the code inside is:

```
class TestClass:
    def repeat(txt:str, num:int):
        counter = 0
        while counter < num:
            print(txt)
            counter = counter + 1
```

I can't call the method after I created the object. Here is the code:

```
testing2 = testing.TestClass()
testing2.repeat('test', 10)
```

Error:

```
#the error is: TypeError: TestClass.repeat() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I think this is a small problem, but explaining its solution will help my understanding a great deal.

Comment: To problem is very basic, but Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation. Look up how to define class methods.

Comment: you should change `def repeat(txt:str, num:int):` to `def repeat(self, txt:str, num:int):`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When you creating a class, you need to follow the basic principles of class realisation. You forgot about `__init__` function which initialize you class, you code need to looks like:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def repeat(self, txt:str, num:int):
        counter = 0
        while counter < num:
            print(txt)
            counter = counter + 1
```

And then all will works

```
testing2 = TestClass()
testing2.repeat('test', 10)
#test
#test
#test
#test
#test
#test
#test
#test
#test
#test
```

Comment: Why super()? This is not a subclass. Also, for the purposes of the OP's question there is no need for __init__ at all

Comment: @LancelotduLac: And even if it was a subclass, a `__init__` that does nothing but invoke `super().__init__` with the same arguments can just be omitted, inheriting the superclass's definition automatically (while being more performant and less verbose to boot).

Answer (score 0):

```py
class TestClass:
    def repeat(self, txt:str, num:int):
        counter = 0
        while counter < num:
            print(txt)
            counter = counter + 1
```

Add an argument (`self`)to the def definition.
You can also initialize your class like this:

```py
testing2 = TestClass()
testing2.repeat('test', 10)
```

Comment: Given they don't use `self` at all, makes more sense to just omit `self` and decorate it with `@staticmethod`.

Comment: @LancelotduLac: `self` doesn't require annotation; it's definitionally treated as the type it's a method on (so `TestClass`, or subclass thereof).

Comment: @LancelotduLac: Which mentions one specific case where, right now, you would need to annotate it (one that doesn't apply here; this isn't returning a new instance of `TestClass` or its children), and proposes a solution that makes it unnecessary to annotate it even in that case (because it doesn't require it, and it's silly and redundant to annotate `self` over and over), only mentioning in passing that you *could* if you wanted to. So I'm not sure what you think referring me there is going to change...?